# KML file displaying Blue polygons not the actual color scheme

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am having trouble displaying polygon kml file on google maps, when open in google earth it shows the actual scheme but when displayed in google maps it just show light blue polygons, I am using the basic google maps api code but of no luck.

[KML in Google Maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDptV.jpg)

[KML in Google Earth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAepm.jpg)

I am using the following code:

```
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: {lat: 38.8, lng: -77.025}
    });

    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
      url: 'https://masonfloodhazardsresearchlab.github.io/PlotData/MWLpotomac.kml',
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like the Google Maps KML renderer isn't working correctly, [if I parse that KML with a third party parser, it shows the colors](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/MWLpotomac.kml) (although it doesn't seem to show the full basin, which appears in the KmlLayer version)

Comment: I turned the full basin layer off , now you should be able to see all the polygons.
What do you suggest will solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't notice that was off (and I saw it on the KmlLayer, so I thought it was missing) [third party parse with updated KML](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/MWLpotomacA.kml). You might look in the issue tracker to see if this issue with the Google Maps API Kml renderer has been reported

Comment: can you guide me to add third party parser in the code I am using ,until then I am trying to get google issue filed

Comment: You can look at the source of my example (although it is more complicated than you need as it supports KML URLs in the URL and will display the same KML with KmlLayer)

Answer (score 0):

Think I have an answer for this one. Although this thread is old it may prove useful for other people.

**The problem:**
So for my application I had used the web version of google maps to implement a KML layer of the UK. It had its own colour scheme, which was showing in google earth but not in my google maps application. In the google maps application, this was displaying as all blue and for the longest time I couldn't work out what the problem was.

**The fix:**
So for whatever reason, exporting the KML file from the web version of google maps seemed to be the issue.
When exporting from google earth web, the KML file is formatted in such a way that it's styles and colour scheme will not show on any other KML viewer.
The boundaries would show fine similar to what you were doing, but when using it in maps it would be all blue (or even white in some KML viewers).

The easy fix involves taking that file and using another KML editor instead (I used Google Earth Pro). I manually edited each polygon under the properties tab to the desired colour scheme and that fixed my problem.